# Modal view inside ui-view not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

I amm trying to implement a modal window inside a ui-view. **All was working fine when the modal template and controller were inside the ui-view, but after separating them in separate folder they don't work.**
Now I am confused on how to link the modal template and controllers with the ui-view templates and controllers. I also want to pass data inside the modal to another ui-view and it seems another battle.

**Names :**

**ui-view** (template: **drinksList.html**, controller: **DrinksListController**)
**modal view** (template: **drinkModal.html**, controller: **DrinkModalController**)

My code structure is :

**ui.route.js**

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', statesManager])

function statesManager($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  .state('allLists', {
    url: '/allLists',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: '/js/components/allLists.html'
      },
      'drinksList@allLists': {
        templateUrl: '/js/components/drinksList/drinksList.html',
        controller: 'DrinksListController'
      },
      'drinkModal@allLists': {
        templateUrl: '/js/components/drinksList/drinkModal/drinkModal.html',
        controller: 'DrinkModalController'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**allLists.html (contains ui-views to load)**

```js
<div ui-view="drinksList"></div>
```

**drinksList.html**

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="showModal()">
```

**DrinksListController**

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('DrinksListController', DrinksListController)

  function DrinksListController($scope, $stateParams, $uibModal, DrinkModalController) {

    $scope.showModal = () => {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/js/components/drinksList/drinkModal/drinkModal.html',
        controller: 'DrinkModalController'
      })
    }
  }
})()
```

**drinkModal.html**

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form ng-submit="addFood($event)">
    <p>Drink Name : <input ng-model="drinkName" type="text"></p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**DrinkModalController**

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('DrinkModalController', DrinkModalController)

  function DrinkModalController($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.cancel = () => {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel')
    }
  }
})()
```

I just realized that I have '**DrinkModalController**' in index.html (loading script file), ui.route.js, DrinksListController.js and DrinkListModal.js files (in 4 locations). Not sure about this -_-
Thanks for reading all this.